# To prevent a function from printing in the batch console

Tags: python, printing, batch-file

Well, the headline seems to me sufficient.
I use some function that at some points print something in the console.
As I can't modify them, I would like to know if there is a solution to not printing while using these functions.

Comment: What's the `batch console`? Are you talking about `stdout`?

Comment: That's a sign of bad design. If possible, fix the function. Otherwise, if the function is using Python's `print`, you could temporarily replace `sys.stdout` with an object with an empty `write` method.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, you can redirect `sys.stdout`:

```
import sys
import os

old_stdout = sys.stdout # backup current stdout
sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, "w")

my_nasty_function()

sys.stdout = old_stdout # reset old stdout
```

Just replace `my_nasty_function` with your actual function.

**EDIT:** Now should work on windows aswell.

**EDIT:** Use backup variable to reset stdout is better when someone wraps your function again

Comment: There's no need for `backup_stdout`, as you can use `sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__` to restore the original (see [here](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.__stdout__)). Also, it would be better to use [`os.devnull`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.devnull), so that it will work on Windows.

Comment: @ekhumoro `backup_stdout` is a better solution since your code can be treated by the caller with similar measures :) I mean, *restoring* `stdout` should actually *restore* the initial value, and not *set* it to something arbitrary.

Comment: What are the hazards if the nasty function throws an error? I want to know how this should be modified to be production-ready.

Comment: @AlanSE You can wrap the `my_nasty_function()` in a `try/finally` block (put the resetting of the `stdout` (`sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__ `) in the finally, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 9):

[Constantinius' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8447352/60711) answer is ok, however there is no need to actually open null device. And BTW, if you want portable null device, there is [`os.devnull`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.devnull).

Actually, all you need is a class which will ignore whatever you write to it. So more portable version would be:

```
class NullIO(StringIO):
    def write(self, txt):
       pass

sys.stdout = NullIO()

my_nasty_function()

sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

.

Answer (score 7):

Another option would be to wrap your function in a decorator.

```py
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from io import StringIO 

class NullIO(StringIO):
    def write(self, txt):
        pass


def silent(fn):
    """Decorator to silence functions."""
    def silent_fn(*args, **kwargs):
        with redirect_stdout(NullIO()):
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return silent_fn


def nasty():
    """Useful function with nasty prints."""
    print('a lot of annoying output')
    return 42


# Wrap in decorator to prevent printing.
silent_nasty = silent(nasty)
# Same output, but prints only once.
print(nasty(), silent_nasty())
```

Comment: There's a case typo in the StringIO import (`from io import stringIO`)

Comment: within silent_fn, it should return fn(*args, **kwargs)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a modified version of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3378965/355230) to create a "null" output context to wrap the call the function in.

That can be done by just passing [`os.devnull`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.devnull) as the `new_stdout` argument to the `stdout_redirected()` context manager function when it's used.

Answer (score 1):

Constantinius' solution will work on *nix, but this should work on any platform:

```
import sys
import tempfile

sys.stdout = tempfile.TemporaryFile()

# Do crazy stuff here

sys.stdout.close()
#now the temp file is gone
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

Comment: You forgot to redirect `sys.stdout`.

Comment: So I did.  I'm not properly caffinated yet :\

Comment: Not a good solution, it will create actual file on the disk, meaning totally unnecessary disk IO and possibility of running out of disk space.

Answer (score 1):

The currently accepted answer by [Constantinius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/746961/constantinius) works great in most circumstances, but not in Jupyter notebooks.
Here's how to get it to work (with a reusable function)...

*TLDR~Instead of using `sys.__stout__`, backup `sys.stdout` and restore it later on.*

In a Jupyter notebook, running `sys.stdout == sys.__stdout__` returns false. This is because each cell has a separate output stream (instead of the one terminal instance, which is `sys.__stdout__`).
So for everyone working with Jupyter notebooks, make sure to back up the old `sys.stdout` path and restore it afterwards.
Here's a function for it:

```py
import sys, os
def deafen(function, *args):
    real_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, "w")
    output = function(*args)
    sys.stdout = real_stdout
    return output
```

Pass to `deafen` a function along with its arguments/parameters (`args`). It backs up the old `sys.stdout`, switches to `os.devnull` and back again itself.

For a complete example we can create a second function (`test_function`):

```py
def test_function(first_argument, second_argument, *args):
    print(first_argument)
    print(second_argument)
    print(args)
```

Now if we try using the `test_function` like normal (a.k.a. without `deafen`) we will get a bunch of output printed onto the screen:

```py
print("Printing should work fine here")
test_function(32, 12, 1, 32, 1)
```

However, when using `deafen`, we'll get no new output:

```py
print("That'll be the last thing you see...")
deafen(test_function, 32, 12, 1, 32, 1)
```

On a side note, the `deafen` function still returns a functions output. You can also use `deafen` with `sys.__stdout__` by replacing `sys.stdout = real_stdout` with `sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__` (and may as well remove `real_stdout = sys.stdout` whilst you're at it).

Hope that helps anyone who is looking for a slightly more robust or flexible solution (likely for Jupyter notebooks, or use with multiple functions)!