# iPython notebook avoid printing within a function

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want to prevent a function to print in iPython notebook.

In standard python one can prevent printing some lines of code as answered in the question: [To prevent a function from printing in the batch console in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447185/to-prevent-a-function-from-printing-in-the-batch-console-in-python)
However this method do not work in iPython notebook, losing the output until a restart of the Kernel.

The most similar feature I found is to avoid a full cell to display using the magic function:

```
%%capture capt
```

However this magic function blocks the whole cell, is there any way in iPython notebook to avoid printing just some of the lines within the code?

Comment: Perhaps you can wrap the code in a [`with io.capture_output():` statement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14573397/190597).

Comment: However I think this is not duplicated. Despite the solution is the same, the question is clearly diferent, and they solve diferents problems.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use [io.capture_output](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/api/generated/IPython.utils.io.html#IPython.utils.io.capture_output):

```
from IPython.utils import io

with io.capture_output() as captured:
    foo()
```

to capture stdout and stderr for only those lines within the `with-statement`.