# How do you suppress output in Jupyter running IPython?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

How can output to `stdout` be suppressed?

A semi-colon can be used to supress display of returned objects, for example

```
>>> 1+1
2

>>> 1+1;   # No output!
```

However, a function that prints to stdout is not affected by the semi-colon.

```
>>> print('Hello!')
Hello!

>>> MyFunction()
Calculating values...
```

How can the output from `print` / `MyFunction` be suppressed?

Comment: for iruby kernel just add     `nil`     as the last line

Answer (score 301, accepted):

Add `%%capture` as the first line of the cell. eg

```
%%capture
print('Hello')
MyFunction()
```

This simply discards the output, but the `%%capture` magic can be used to save the output to a variable - [consult the docs](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Cell%20Magics.ipynb)

Comment: Anyone know what the opposite of %%capture is? As in, how do you stop %%capture within a cell, or is it enabled until the end of the cell?

Comment: Good thing to know is `%%capture` is only enabled until the end of the cell, and it must appear before any code in the cell. (So it appears there isn't a way to uncapture within a cell.)

Comment: ICYMI, @David Parks and @Arel's discussion is covered by @gwd2's answer on this page about using `with io.capture_output() as captured:` you can fine-tune within a cell to only capture what is run in that `with` context.

Comment: Note this only works for Python kernels (e.g. not R).

Comment: It does not discard warnings, in my case I use tensorflow.keras and get their warnings.

Comment: For your information, `%%capture cap` and `cap.show()` show the contents of the standard outputs.

Comment: Uhh maybe this changed: UsageError: Line magic function `%%capture` not found.

Answer (score 143):

## Suppress output

##### Put a `;` at the end of a line to suppress the printing of output [[Reference](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/tips.html)].

A good practice is to always return values from functions rather than printing values inside a function. In that case, you have the control; if you want to print the returned value, you can; otherwise, it will not be printed just by adding a ; after the function call.

Comment: This doesn't for a code inside a `for` loop. Any ideas? I only want to suppress output from particular lines of code in the cell, not all lines. Thanks

Comment: this method doesn't work for `print()` at jupyter notebook. however, codes like `1+1;` works.

Comment: Also doesn't work for some 3rd party components; it seems to be supressing only native python stdout.

Comment: did you not read the question, he explicitly said he wanted something else

Comment: Actually, jupyter will not print the value of the variable unless this is the last statement of the cell. If it is the last statement, the semicolon will suppress the output as you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped prevent icecream's `ic` from printing twice.

Comment: Can you please add an example?

Comment: this doesn't work when trying to run instabot :( Still get a bunch of garbage back cuz it's so broken.

Answer (score 53):

(credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23611571/389812)

You could use [io.capture_output](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/api/generated/IPython.utils.io.html#IPython.utils.io.capture_output):

```
from IPython.utils import io

with io.capture_output() as captured:
    MyFunction()
```

to supress (e.g. capture) stdout and stderr for those lines within the `with-statement`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was driving me crazy -- I have a startup function that I run every time I open a notebook that calls `%autosave`, and wanted to suppress its output. Thought it would be simple -- but weirdly, `contextlib.redirect_stdout` and `sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')` both fail (end up printing an extra blank line). This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This was my favourite answer, because one can suppress *some* of the output in a cell without suppressing all of it.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: thank you for saving a life

Comment: this doesn't work when trying to run instabot :( Still get a bunch of garbage back cuz it's so broken.

Comment: Note that `capture_output(stdout=True, stderr=True)` lets you choose whether to capture `stdout`, `stderr` or both with the appropriate settings.

Answer (score 2):

`pip install ipython-extensions`

```
%%capture

print("hello")
#This cell will not return any output
```

`%%Capture` is a magic command to suppress the output of the cell in Jupiter notebook. But to run that you will have to install `ipython-extensions` first.

Comment: Modern Jupyter includes this already & so there is nothing needed to install. And even if that was true, it could be simply a comment to [the most upvoted answer already here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23692951/8508004) because your answer covers no new ground in regards to the answer.

Answer (score -7):

If anyone is interested in clearing all outputs:

1. Go to **Cell**
2. Go to **All Output**

Then choose whichever option you like.