# frequency histogram with matplotlib--how to get rid of the array display?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I creating a simple frequency histogram:

```
figure(figsize=(12,9))

ax=subplot(111)
#Get rid of the border lines
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)

#Axis label
xlabel("Gross Earnings", fontsize=16)  
ylabel("Frequency (in thousands)", fontsize=16) 

#Limit the x range so we can see the distribution more closely
xlim(0, 40000)

#Ticks
ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
ax.get_yaxis().tick_left()

hist(earnings, weights=wgts, color="#3F5D7D", bins=100)
```

I get the histogram alright, but I also get the giant arrays earnings and wgts in display. How do I get rid of those?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `;` to the end of your line with `hist`. This will [suppress output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692950/how-do-you-suppress-output-in-ipython-notebook) in general, but in particular for graphing calls. (When graphing, ironically, the output is irrelevant; it is a side-effect of the call that shows the plot.)