# Python in terminal: how to signify end of for loop?

Tags: python, terminal

Say I want to print `0` through `9`.

I type in `for i in range(10): print(i)`, press <kbd>enter</kbd>, and terminal shows `...`, waiting for further statements.

So I have to press <kbd>enter</kbd> again to have the numbers printed.

```
>>> for i in range(10): print(i)
...
```

How can I have the number printed without having to press <kbd>enter</kbd> twice?

Comment: Are you asking how to execute a command without pressing `enter` to execute your command...?

Comment: @crookedleaf No...So I type `for i in range(10): print(i)`, enter, and it gives `...` waiting for more statements. So I have to press enter twice.

Comment: Then what exactly are you asking?

Comment: Do you want something like `[i for i in range(10)]`?

Comment: @SamShen this is just the way the terminal works since you are trying to execute a multi-line command on one line. it's waiting for confirmation that you are done.

Comment: Press enter after the command. You now only have to press enter once.

Comment: @crookedleaf Thank you - yeah I just wondered if there's a way to signify "I'm done" using that one line.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just type the two returns and move on. But since you ask, this only needs one <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
exec("for i in range(10): print(i)")
```

Answer (score 7):

"alt+enter"
I was working in ipython and facing the same problem as yours. upon trying various combinations from keyboard, this one finally worked

Comment: I don't think this works in the regular python terminal which is different than iPython terminal

Comment: For reference, this works in the standard Mac OS terminal, except that the keys become `option+enter`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Shift+Enter to end the function or loop which continues next line as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Convert your for-loop into a so-called **list comprehension** (you don't need `eval` / `exec` and wrap the whole thing in a string as the current top answer suggests):

```
In [1]: [i for i in range(3)]
Out[1]: [0, 1, 2]
```

You can also keep your `print()` statement if you want it on multiple lines, but the return value (`None`) will be put in the array that is returned, so you'll get this:

```
In [2]: [print(i) for i in range(3)]
0
1
2
Out[2]: [None, None, None]
```

To suppress that final output line, you can [add a semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43265298/1201863):

```
In [3]: [print(i) for i in range(3)];
0
1
2
```

So much for `ipython3`, but perhaps more usefully, what about command-line usage? You can't do `python3 -c 'import sys; for line in sys.stdin: print(line)'` but you *can* use list comprehension:

```
$ python3 -c '[print(i) for i in range(3)]'
0
1
2
```

So if you want to run a bit of python over each line:

```
$ cat inputfile
two
examples
$ cat inputfile | python3 -c 'import sys; [print(line.strip().upper()) for line in sys.stdin]'
TWO
EXAMPLES
```

(You can replace `cat infile |` with `<infile` but this seemed more accessible for those not familiar with Bash syntax, and those who are familiar can trivially replace it.)

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the for statement without using the exec() by pressing enter to go to the next line and then pressing ctrl + d