# fillna function to replce NaN in a dataframe raising IOPub data rate exceeded

Tags: python, jupyter, fillna

New to Python and working my way through a Panda import and cleanse.

My code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('SFIC_RFQs.csv', sep='~', usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19, 20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30, 31,32])
df.isnull().sum().sum()               # Total Number of NaN = 14594
df.fillna(0)
```

Error:

> IOPub data rate exceeded
>       The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output to the client in order to avoid crashing it. To change this limit, set the config variable `--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

I changed `C:\Users\pelucas\.jupyter\ jupyter_notebook_config` from

```
#c.NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit = 1000000
```

to

```
#c.NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit = 100000000000
```

Same error

I amended the `fillna` command to `df.iloc[0:1500,0:33].fillna(value=0,inplace=true)` so as to see if it worked, It did but as soon as I oushed up to `df.iloc[0:1600,0:33]` the error above was raised again.

The `fillna` function is [displaying the results of it's action in the Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihimv.png) which I guess is the issue.

1. Is there a way to force Jupyter to not show the results of the fillna command? Or if it has to just display plain text?
2. I imported 33 columns (0:33) but my fillna command has 0:33 impying 34 coluns or is the zero element an internal index?
3. My read_csv looks a little long, can I abbreviated the column numbers i.e. 0:33?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692950/how-do-you-suppress-output-in-ipython-notebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: if you want to use the output of `fillna` you should add  `inplace=True` to your command or assign this line to another variable. If you'll assign it to antoher variable (`new_df = df.fillna(0)`) you will also avoid displaying the output.

Instead you can add another line to the block with output that can help you understand the data:

```
new_df.sample(50)
```

or

```
new_df.head(50)
```

Comment: Thanks AndreyF,. Works well. cheers
df_No_NaN = df.fillna(0) has no output and  df_No_NaN.isnull().sum().sum()  is zero

Comment: So no other way to use df.fillna(0) without outputting the result and raising that i/O error?