# How to limit cell text output in Google Colaboratory?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Is it possible to limit the number of lines output by a code cell in Google Colaboratory? As to mimic the behavior of the command shell that keeps only the last *n* lines?

Sometimes it happens that the browser crashes because of the size of the generated tab, due to the huge amount of text produced by debug text.

Is there a solution without having to reduce the amount of text actually generated by the code itself?

Answer (score 0):

Add `%%capture` to the top of the cell to completely discard the output.

Found on: [How do you suppress output in IPython Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692950/how-do-you-suppress-output-in-ipython-notebook)