# How to suppress output in Google Colaboratory cell which executes a command line script (line starts with `!`) via a function

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter, google-colaboratory

In Google colab I execute command line scripts by place a `!` in front of the line and executing the cell.

For example

```
!pip install adjustText
```

If I want to prevent output of this cell, I can do this

```
%%capture
!pip install adjustText
```

However, I have a situation where I execute the command line scripts via a function, and suppress output for that command line only, without suppressing the output of the cell from which it's being executed

For example

Cell1:

```
%%capture
def installAdjust():
    !pip install adjustText
```

Cell2:

```
for v in range(10):
    print(v)
    installAdjust()
```

This does not suppress the output from `!pip install adjustText`. I do not want to suppress the non-command line output from Cell2, so I can Not do this

Cell2:

```
%%capture
for v in range(10):
    print(v)
    installAdjust()
```

Also, this doesn't work either

Cell1:

```
def installAdjust():
   %%capture
    !pip install adjustText
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `capture_output` from python's utilities:

```
from IPython.utils import io
for v in range(10):
    print(v)
    with io.capture_output() as captured:
      installAdjust()
```

For the future, whenever a magic function doesn't suffice, search for the core properties being accessed and access them yourself.

> Answer sourced from: *[How do you suppress output in IPython Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692950/how-do-you-suppress-output-in-ipython-notebook)*

Answer (score 35):

you can use '%%capture' magic function in a cell(without quotes) to suppress the output of that particular cell whether it uses a command-line code or some python code, magic function is basically a property of jupyter notebooks but since google colab is built over this, it will work there also.
eg:

```
%%capture
!wget https://github.com/09.10-20_47_44.png
```

Comment: Wow this answer saved my day!

Comment: Hm, this doesn't work for me, I still get the output printed below the cell. Do I have to reload the notebook or something?

Comment: Not actually, it works for me even without reloading the notebook, What specifically you run?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something very simple. Below code will clear the output generated by the code.

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
pip install <package-name>
clear_output()
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply append to the command an output redirection:

Redirect output AND errors, add `&> /dev/null`

```
!mkdir /content/notexist/blah &> /dev/null
```

Redirect output, but NOT errors, add `> /dev/null`

```
!mkdir /content/notexist/yeaa > /dev/null
```

In the example below, both commands fail, but we ignore the error from the second.

[image]

Specifically for your case, the code would be:

```
%%capture
def installAdjust():
    !pip install adjustText &> /dev/null
```