# How to silent or redirect output of shutil.move() or another method to move files in silent mode?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, shutil

Was using Python shutil.move() method but need to move million files from one location to another and I would like to redirect / silent the output of shutil.move().

```
if os.path.exists(logs_path_archive):
    for source_file in downloaded_files:
        destination_file = source_file.replace(logs_path,logs_path_archive)
        shutil.move(source_file,destination_file)
```

Any recommendation?

Comment: Do you want to redirect all the output of python script ?

Comment: What output does shutil.move produce that you need to silence?

Comment: Does echo of the filename being moved, then I would like to silent the output or for the specific shutil line, executed in a ipython cell (jupyter notebook) to redirect to /dev/null or another file instead of the output of the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comment you specify, you are using a Jupyter Notebooks. So you can use a couple of options built into IPython/Jupyter for that.

If the move step is just one cell, at the start of the cell put the following:

```py
%%capture out_stream
shutil.move(<original_filename>,<new_file_name>)
```

However, it sounds like the move step is in amongst many other steps in a cell, and so to just hush the move, you can use the `with io.capture_output() as captured:` to suppress output from only what is in the `with` block, like so:

```py
from IPython.utils import io
with io.capture_output() as captured:
    shutil.move(<original_filename>,<new_file_name>)
```

See the page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52559560/8508004) for more about both of those. The `%%capture` cell magic will probably be above where that link sends you.

---

If you do need to use pure python you can use a `with` statement and [contextlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html) (like a contextmanager to handle output) to redirect that, similar to the `with io.capture_output() as captured` idea above. Here I'm sending it to `_` which is often used when you don't plan to use the object assigned later.

```py
import contextlib
with contextlib.redirect_stdout(_):
    shutil.move(<original_filename>,<new_file_name>)
```