# How to suppress Tensorflow Training Log in Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Training a sequential model in a notebook gives very long output over the training epochs. How to suppress this output? Or how to general suppress outputs of a single Code-cell?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you suppress output in Jupyter running IPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692950/how-do-you-suppress-output-in-jupyter-running-ipython)

Comment: If you just want the printed output of model.fit  to be prevented from printing set verbose = 0 in model.fit

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code snippet before importing Tensorflow

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').disabled = True
```

It will suppress the Tensorflow log information.