# How to disable logging from PyTorch-Lightning logger?

Tags: python, logging, pytorch-lightning

Logger in PyTorch-Lightning prints information about the model to be trained (or evaluated) and the progress during the training,

However, in my case I would like to hide all messages from the logger in order not to flood the output in `Jupyter Notebook`.

I've looked into the API of the Trainer class on the official docs page https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common/trainer.html#trainer-flags and it seems like there is no option to turn off the messages from the logger.

There is a parameter `log_every_n_steps` which can be set to big value, but nevertheless, the logging result after each epoch is displayed.

How can one disable the logging?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am assuming that two things are particularly bothering you in terms of flooding output stream:

One, The "weight summary":

```
  | Name | Type   | Params
--------------------------------
0 | l1   | Linear | 100 K 
1 | l2   | Linear | 1.3 K 
--------------------------------
...
```

Second, the progress bar:

```
Epoch 0:  74%|███████████   | 642/1874 [00:02<00:05, 233.59it/s, loss=0.85, v_num=wxln]
```

PyTorch Lightning provided very clear and elegant solutions for turning them off: `Trainer(progress_bar_refresh_rate=0)` for turning off progress bar and `Trainer(weights_summary=None)` for turning off weight summary.

Comment: `progress_bar_refresh_rate` seems to be deprecated now. It is recommended to use `enable_progress_bar=False`. Or add a `TQDMProgressBar` Callback and adapt it's `refresh_rate`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try like that?

```
logging.getLogger("package").propagate = False
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, the problem still remains

Answer (score 0):

The solution was the combination of the @Artyrm Sergeev suggestion and the answer suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52559560/13614416.

1. Get all `pytorch_lightning` loggers:

   pl_loggers = [
   logging.getLogger(name)
   for name in logging.root.manager.loggerDict
   if 'pytorch_lightning' in name
   ]
2. Put the `trainer.fit` inside following construction:

   with io.capture_output() as captured: trainer.fit(...)