# How to get rid of INFO logging messages in PyTorch lightning

Tags: logging, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I'm using PyTorch Lightning and I call the method `seed_everything()`, but I don't want to see the INFO logging message

```
Global seed set to 1234
```

on every iteration of my main algorithm.

I've tried `logging.getLogger('pytorch_lightning').setLevel(logging.ERROR)` in the constructor of the PL object, but it doesn't work. Also tried what is suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68834206/892904), but it doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```py
import logging
log = logging.getLogger("pytorch_lightning")
log.propagate = False
log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Comment: After over an hour of trying other suggestions in other StackOverflow questions, this is the only approach that worked for me. To get it to work for a unit test, I had to put all but the import statement into the body of the unit test itself.

Comment: This no longer worked for me. The reason however is that in newer versions quite a lot of the code moved to the `lightning_fabric` library (which is a dependency of `pytorch_lightning`). So use `"lightning_fabric"` as the logger name above to fix.

Answer (score 1):

I also found many suggestions, and I finally found a better way. Although the above answer is valid, it will prohibit the output of other information.

You should put the code `seed_everything()` before the log initialization. Just like this:

```
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from pytorch_lightning import seed_everything

seed_everything(1234) 

logger = pl.loggers.TensorBoardLogger(save_dir="logs", name="example")
```