# Boxplot appear differently in definition in Jupyter Book, how can I do? (Windows 10)

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

[image]

The left is a sample, the right is what I print. May I ask how to fix it?

Comment: You can add a semicolon after the last statement to avoid Jupyter writing out its return value.  So: `sns.boxplot(...);`.   You can use `sns.set(font_scale=0.8)` at the start to change all the text sizes.

Comment: You are using newer versions of both seaborn and matplotlib than what you're referring to, and also seem to have your rcparams set differently than the default.

Comment: @JohanC This is useful!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you suppress output in Jupyter running IPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692950/how-do-you-suppress-output-in-jupyter-running-ipython)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by this comment:

You can add a semicolon after the last statement to avoid Jupyter writing out its return value. So: sns.boxplot(...);. You can use sns.set(font_scale=0.8) at the start to change all the text sizes. –
--JohanC