# Is there a way to suppress empty output (`::`) when using the magic %%q (with PyKX, NOT PyQ) in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, kdb, pykx

When using the `%%q` magic with PyKX in jupyter notebook, it seems that the output from each line of code is printed, including `::`. See, e.g., the example on the [documentation](https://code.kx.com/pykx/2.1/getting-started/q_magic_command.html) . Is there a way to suppress empty output (`::`)?

[image]

I tried to add `;` to each line of code, but still a `::` is printed for each line of code ended with `;`. I expect all output of `::` to be removed, or only the output of the last line of code in a cell is printed with all results of previous lines removed (even if that line is not ended with `;`).

Comment: There isn't a way to do this at the moment within the library but certainly can be added, the team and I will take a look at implementing this in a coming release

Comment: By the way, you are mistaken about how/why code ended with `;` can sometimes not cause 'extra' things to be printed. A good example is Matplotlib plots often commonly  involve ending code with this trick. It worked there because the last thing that is in a typical cell gets evaluated and what it returns displayed and often it would have some code about the Matplotlib object that people didn't want to see. Adding the `;` made that the last expression on the line and it returns nothing and so the spurious object code info is suppressed. That isn't the case here for `::` getting generated...

Comment: <continued> and so the `;` trick doesn't work here. I see the developer says it is isn't possible now and so that is probably the answer. I was going to suggest maybe using some Jupyter tricks but I don't know if it will play well with the `%%q` cel magic you are using here. There is this `%%capture` trick described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23692951/8508004) that may work if put on the second or first line? And if it is coming as a C-level message you can use wurlitzer in the cell. But both of these necessitate other steps to see you actual output so probably not helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. For `%%capture`, I'm not sure if it can be directly combined with `%%q`, probably need some other stuff to do... I'm also thinking about possible jupyter trick (probably some javascript function?), e.g. to recognize a single line of `::` in the output and remove that line, but I'm not that familiar with that..

Answer (score 0):

I find an interim solution by defining a customized magic command which mimics the one in PyKX (defined here: https://github.com/KxSystems/pykx/blob/main/src/pykx/nbextension.py). In my usecase, I don't mind adding the definition at the top of each notebook, so I just add the following code to define a new magic command `%%qq` to do the same stuff. I also don't use any options of the PyKX q magic command, so I remove those code.

```py
import pykx as kx
from IPython.core.magic import register_cell_magic

@register_cell_magic
def qq(instructions, code):
    ld = kx.SymbolAtom('.Q.pykxld')
    _q = kx.q
    code = [kx.CharVector(x) for x in code.split('\n')][:-1]
    ret = _q(
        "{[ld;code;file] value (@';\"q\";enlist[file],/:value(ld;code))}",
        ld,
        code,
        b'jupyter_cell.q'
    )
    if not ret[-1] == kx.q('::'):
        print(_q('{x y}', ret, kx.q.count(ret)-1)
```

For more details, see https://github.com/KxSystems/pykx/issues/7