# Disable warnings in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm getting this warning in jupyter notebook.

```
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:10: DeprecationWarning: object of type <class 'float'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer.
  # Remove the CWD from sys.path while we load stuff.
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:11: DeprecationWarning: object of type <class 'float'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer.
  # This is added back by InteractiveShellApp.init_path()
```

It's annoying because it shows up in every run I do:

[image]

How do I fix or disable it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop IPython Notebook from printing warnings / status updates to terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33572118/stop-ipython-notebook-from-printing-warnings-status-updates-to-terminal)

Answer (score 112):

If you are sure your code is correct and simple want to get rid of this warning **and all other warnings in the notebook** do the following:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Comment: This should be the validated answer !

Comment: doesn't work for me (nor do any other answers), see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69544407/5125264

Answer (score 25):

Try this:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
```

Answer (score 12):

You can also suppress warnings just for some lines of code:

```py
import warnings

def function_that_warns():
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    function_that_warns()  # this will not show a warning
```

Answer (score 2):

None of these answers work if you are arriving from google, I finally found a solution ([credit to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23611571/5125264))

```py
from IPython.utils import io

with io.capture_output() as captured:
    foo()
```

Answer (score 2):

Just run this snippet at the top of your code:

```
!pip install shutup
##At the top of the code
import shutup;
shutup.please()
```

Answer (score 1):

You will get this warning if you pass an argument as float, that should be an integer.

E.g., in the following example, `num` should be an integer, but is passed as float:

```
import numpy as np
np.linspace(0, 10, num=3.0)
```

This prints the warning you got:

```
ipykernel_launcher.py:2: DeprecationWarning: object of type <class 'float'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer.
```

Since parts of your code are missing, I cannot figure out, which parameter should be passed as integer, but the following example shows how to fix this:

```
import numpy as np
np.linspace(0, 10, num=int(3.0))
```