# Cannot supress Python Warnings with warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, warnings

I am using the following to suppress my warnings. Sometimes the warning are suppressed, while more recently they are of no use and the warnings still appear.

```
> import warnings  
> warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

I am using Jupyter-notebook and working with Tensorflow (also with Keras, but not for this particular question, but the same thing happens with Keras as well)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it stopped working maybe you forgot to execute first the cell with the ignoring code?

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
```

Please note the additional line as per [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53759796/6573902) to [Disable warnings in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48828824/disable-warnings-in-jupyter-notebook).