# using warnings.filterwarnings() to convert a warning into an exception

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to programatically capture when statsmodels.api.OLS raises its "The smallest eigenvalue is ..." warning

This would enable me to filter a large number of OLS systems by whether or not they raise this warning

Ideally, I would like to pick off just particular warnings instead of a blanket filter for any/all warnings

My attempt (below) attempts a blanket filter using warnings.filterwarnings() , it doesn't work

How do I get warnings.filterwarnings() to work?  Or is there some other module I should be looking at instead?

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import warnings

np.random.seed(123)

nrows = 100

colA = np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.0, nrows)
colB = np.random.uniform(0.0 ,1.0, nrows)
colC = colA + colB  # multicolinear data to generate ill-conditioned system
y = colA + 2 * colB + np.random.uniform(0.0, 0.1, nrows)
X = pd.DataFrame({'colA': colA, 'colB': colB, 'colC': colC})

warnings.filterwarnings('error')  # achieves nothing

warnings.simplefilter('error')
# from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59961735/cannot-supress-python-warnings-with-warnings-filterwarningsignore
# also achieves nothing

try:
    model = sm.OLS(y, sm.add_constant(X)).fit()
    print(model.summary())
except:
    print('warning successfully captured in try-except')
```

Comment: You may have to dig around in the source code to see if it is actually using python warnings system. Seeing the actual full warning may also give some clues.

Comment: Turns out it wasn't a warning, just a print() with the word "warning" in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the smallest eigenvalue using `model.eigenvals[-1]`, just check that it is less than `1e-10` to raise an exception. Here's the [source](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.html#OLS) that generates the note

```py
errstr = ("The smallest eigenvalue is %6.3g. This might indicate that there are\n"
          "strong multicollinearity problems or that the design matrix is singular.")
try:
    model = sm.OLS(y, sm.add_constant(X)).fit()
    assert model.eigenvals[-1] >= 1e-10, (errstr % model.eigenvals[-1])
    print(model.summary())
except AssertionError as e:
    print('warning successfully captured in try-except. Message below:')
    print(e)
```