# Trouble printing out dictionary.meaning() output using PyDictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pydictionary

I'm trying to make a program that will grab a random word from a JSON file and print it and it's definition using PyDictionary. It works occasionally but I think the issue I am having is displaying output from dictionary.meaning(word) when the word has multiple meanings.  I get an IndexError when that appears the be the case.

> example outputs: expected: tinamidae Noun ['comprising the
>   tinamous']
>
> unwanted result: unmaterially Error: The Following Error occured: list
>   index out of range No definition found!

```
import json
import random
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary

dictionary = PyDictionary()

with open('C:\\Users\\jabes\\Desktop\\words_dictionary.json') as json_file:
    words = json.load(json_file)

    word = random.choice(list(words.keys()))
    print(word)

    try:
        meanings = dictionary.meaning(word)
        if meanings:
            for k,v in meanings.items():
                print(k, v)
        else:
            print("No definition found!")

    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
        print("Exiting!")
```

Comment: Hey Welcome to SO, can you please add the sample input and error you are getting to the question?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I added sample output.  The input is the words that are getting printed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python how to get rid of PyDictionary error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52563826/python-how-to-get-rid-of-pydictionary-error-messages)