# Prevent Paramiko from printing to console

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, stdout, paramiko

When I connect a Paramiko client, I get output I don't need:

> Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_7.2p2)
>   Authentication (publickey) failed.
>   Authentication (publickey) failed.
>   Authentication (password) successful!

I tried to suppress the stdout as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447185/to-prevent-a-function-from-printing-in-the-batch-console-in-python), but it doesn't work:

```
sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, "w")
print("AAAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa")        
my_client.connect(hostname=hostname, username=username, password=password)
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

The "AAAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" does NOT appear, but the output from Paramiko still does.  How do I stop Paramiko's info from printing to the console?

Comment: If the program values the POSIX rules it will write the messages to `stderr` not `stdout`.

Comment: even the first "connected" line and the last "successful!" line?

Comment: What is to be read by the user goes to `stderr`. What is output data goes to `stdout`. It is not always easy to classify these, but your messages are rather clear.

Answer (score 1):

Paramiko does not print anything to the console on its own.

Paramiko sends those messages to a logger ([logging module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)). If they end up on the console, you must have a logger configured that sends the log messages to the console.