# print-like function that writes string to a text file

Tags: python, function, arguments

I would like to write a function in Python that will take arguments just like `print` does but instead of printing the strings to stdout, I would like to write the strings formatted into a text file.

How do I define the arguments for such a function arguments to accept the string formatting, I'm wondering?

I am looking for something that would replace

```
print "Test"
```

with

```
MyLog "Test"
```

but the % rguments should also be supported.
So far I have only come up with this:

```
def logger(txt):    
fh = open (LOGFILE, "a") #Get handle in append mode
fh.write(txt)
fh.close()
print txt
return True
```

which works fine for a simple string but i don't think it'll take the % arguments nor will I be able to call it like *logger "TEST"*

Comment: the same file each time?

Comment: Do you mean you want to write a function you can call like `my_function arg1 arg2` or do you just need a way to write to a file using a builtin function?

Comment: Well, I can e.g. call print "Test" and I would like to be able to just replace print with MyLog "Test" e.g.

Comment: `print` is a statement in Python2.x, and you can't add another statement to the language.  You can however, use specific syntax for `print` as a statement to make it write to a file (e.g. `print >> log_file_object, "Test"`.

Comment: `"string with %s formats %d" % ('3', 3)"` will always evaluate to a string, even as an argument to a function.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the "print chevron" statement to do what you want like this:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
  print >> f, my_object
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print) for the print statement.

Of course, it probably is better practice to use the `print()` function as Martijn Pieters [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13275117/600110).

**Update**

If I change your `logger` function to use the print chevron syntax, I get this:

```
def logger(txt):    
  fh = open (LOGFILE, "a") #Get handle in append mode
  fh.write(txt)
  fh.close()
  print >>fh, txt
  return True
```

If you call this function like:

```
now, duration = 4.0, 2.0
logger("User request at %f time took %f seconds." % (now, duration))
```

You'll have a line in your log file that looks like this:

```
User request at 4.0 time took 2.0 seconds.
```

So you can use this with the `%` formatting (although you really should take a look at the [new-style formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)), but you won't be able to call it like:

```
logger "User request at %f time took %f seconds." % (now, duration)
```

That's because print is a [simple statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html), which is a language level construct, and you can't add those to Python.

Comment: Fine, except that that `print` is a statement, not a function.

Comment: True -- but it seems that the OP is looking for a statement, not a function from the way he wants to invoke it.

Comment: @cerr I've updated my answer -- I don't think you can get Python to do exactly what you want, but I've added how you can get close, and why you can't get closer.

Answer (score 4):

[`print()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) *already* lets you do that:

```
print(somestring, file=someopenfile)
```

If you are on python 2, use `from __future__ import print_function` to get the same functionality.

You can always implement a function with the same arguments as the `print` function and use that as a replacement, or use wildcard arguments (`*args`, `**kw`), then add the `file` keyword argument as needed. You can always reach the *original* builtin `print()` function via the `__builtins__` structure:

```
def print(*args, **kw):
    if 'file' not in kw:
        # print to a file instead of stdout
        kw['file'] = someopenfile
    return __builtins__.print(*args, **kw)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since by default `print` outputs to `sys.stdout`, you could create a [`contextmanager`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=contextmanager#context-manager-types) as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3378965/355230) of mine, which would allow you to use regular `print`, regardless of whether you're using the statement or a function version.